# Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, array

Hola estoy haciendo un *sistema de cursos online en **CMV***. Estoy con un problema que no se como resolver y toda ayuda será bienvenida.

Después que el alumno hace login aparece los cursos en  que el está registrado pero cuando selecciona el curso que aparece debería de abril el mismo pero, presenta el error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ead\models\alunos.php on line 33.
```

**AQUI ES LA PARTE DONDE APARECE LOS CURSOS**

```
<?php foreach($cursos as $curso): ?>
<!--link dos cursos -->
<a href="<?php echo BASE; ?>cursos/entrar/<?php echo $curso['id_curso']; ?>">

<div class="cursoitem">
<!--imagem do curso -->
<img src="<?php echo BASE; ?>assets/images/cursos/<?php echo $curso['imagem']; ?>" border="0" width="260" height="150" /><br/><br/>
<!--nome do curso -->
<strong><?php echo $curso['nome']; ?></strong><br/><br/>
<!--descricao do curso -->
<?php echo $curso['descricao']; ?>
</div>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

AQUI APARECE EL ERROR

```php
public function isInscrito($id_curso) {
        
// Esta es la line 33
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM aluno_curso WHERE id_aluno =
 '".($this->info['id'])."' AND id_curso = '$id_curso'";

 var_dump($sql);
 $sql = $this->db->query($sql);
        

    if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece que el error esta en el tipo de dato de `$this->info['id']` parece ser un `Array` y no un `String`, por favor imprimelo con `var_dump` y lo veras

Comment: @Josbert gracias por el  comentario. Ya puse el var_dump y aparece asi: string(69) "SELECT * FROM aluno_curso WHERE id_aluno = '1' AND id_curso = 'Array'"

Comment: allí esta tu problema, dice `..._curso = 'Array'` pero tienes que hacer el `var_dump` es sobre `$this->info['id']` o sea `var_dump($this->info['id'])`

Comment: @Josbert cuando hago var... en esa parte parece : string(1) "1, entoces quieres decir que ese es el error y no el array que aparece asi:  AND id_curso = 'Array'".

Comment: Entonces es correcta esa variable, tal vez deberías concatenarla sin los paréntesis, ya que no son necesarios y desconozco si podrían ser la causa del error, o sea algo así: `...WHERE id_aluno =
 '" . $this->info['id'] . "' AND...`

Comment: En el parámetro `$id_curso` es donde te está llegando un `array`. Antes de la línea 33 es donde debes poner el `var_dump($id_curso)`. Si te devuelve un `array` debes verificar la manera en que le estás pasando este parámetro al modelo.

Comment: @DjCrazy  el var... me devuelve : array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }, pero no se como corregirlo.

Comment: @everson ya que el arreglo tiene esa forma entonces intenta acceder a la posicion 0 del array $id_curso, para que obtengas la posicion del arreglo donde esta el id del alumno que estas intentando acceder, de esta forma podrias probar: $sql = "SELECT * FROM aluno_curso WHERE id_aluno =
 '".($this->info['id'])."' AND id_curso = '".$id_curso[0].'";

Comment: Gracias a todos por el aporte, encontre una manera de corregirlo, despues del parámetro de la function he puesto un implode, tambien la manera que @Francisco Quijada propuso tambien funciona y deja el ccodigo más limpio.

Comment: @Francisco Quijada gracias por tu ayuda.